# Check result of mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt

I used MCRYPT_ENCRYPT and this method:

```
class Encrypter {
    private static $Key = "dublin";
    public static function encrypt ($input) {
        $output = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                                md5(Encrypter::$Key), $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                                md5(md5(Encrypter::$Key))));
        return $output;
    }

    public static function decrypt ($input) {
        $output = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(Encrypter::$Key),
                        base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
                        md5(md5(Encrypter::$Key))), "\0");
        return $output;
    }

}
```

But I need to perform a check of the result to decrypt.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks!

Comment: use the output of crypt as the input of decrypt and it should equal what you started with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to know how to use your class for checking decryption result. If so, the class can be used like this:

```
$originalMessage = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$encryptedMessage = Encrypter::encrypt($originalMessage);
$decryptedMessage = Encrypter::decrypt($encryptedMessage);

echo $encryptedMessage . PHP_EOL; //prints encrypted message
echo $decryptedMessage . PHP_EOL; //prints decrypted message

//checks if decrypted message is the same as original
var_dump($decryptedMessage == $originalMessage);
```

This will print:

```
2tysbFwsmf2YKOBzgafJuHk66zuPjVp8g9E7bsSkPOIBTHlq0SKMeTNbd+/HzxoponxD5eyppxWmUAflJJjM4A==
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
bool(true)
```

First line is encrypted message,
second line is decrypted message,
last line is boolean that indicates whether decrypted message is the same as original one.